# jQuery .attr returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML with the element .replyLink and an input field with type hidden that has a value (in this case 462). I want to be able to get the value of the value attribute of the input .hddnScrapId when I click on the .replyLink element. This is the HTML:

```
<div class="scrapItemParent">
    <input class="hddnScrapId" type="hidden" value="462"/>
    <img class="scrapProfilePic" src=" static/img/user/personalProfilePicture/mod_50_50/150972db1a0c9e863746c12797398b6e40ae05c8.jpg" />
    <div class="scrapContent"><br />
        <video class="scrapVideo" controls>
            <source src="../../../scrapll_m/static/vid/4045e7944d8ea8f10dd4826a1e1595a7cef73b0c.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video><br />
        <span class="scrapTime">2014-05-27 16:51:22<br />Erol Simsir
            <a class="replyLink" href="javascript:void(0);">Reply</a>
            <a class="replyClose" href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JS I have now:

```
$('.replyLink').click(function(){ 
    var hddnScrapId = $(this).closest(".hddnScrapId").attr("value");
    alert(hddnScrapId);
});
```

This keeps saying 'undefined'. I guess the problem occurs because the closest() function can't find the input field hddnScrapId. Why doesn't it work?

Comment: _"Why doesn't it work?"_ Have you read the documentation for `.closest()`?

Comment: how many `.hddnScrapId` do you have, why do you need `closest` at all?

Comment: @mfunkyside - it seems OP thought jQuery would work out which was the closest (nearest) `hddnScrapId` instead of looking at what the function does.

Comment: Use `.val()` not `attr('value')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) only looks among the element itself and its ancestors and the `.hddnScrapId` element isn't a parent of the clicked element.

2) To get the uptodate value, you must use `val`, not `attr("value")`.

You want this :

```
var hddnScrapId = $(this).closest(".scrapItemParent").find(".hddnScrapId").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect selector. You can use:

```
var hddnScrapId = $(this).closest('.scrapContent').siblings(".hddnScrapId").attr("value");
alert(hddnScrapId);
```

Comment: `.scrapContent` is sibling of input `.hddnScrapId`